# Spring Boot custom CRUD query

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I am using Spring Boot to create a basic chore tracker webapp. It renders as shown below, however I have hard coded in these digits so you can see what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to query the DB but cannot  get it working yet.
Here is the source if interested.

How can I make a custom CRUD operation to feed to my Thymeleaf html page?
https://github.com/deemack/chores

[image: chore table]

---

The DB has 3x tables as shown, with the completion table just having the foreign keys of the person table and chore table.

[image]

---

**Completion.java (model)**

```java
package org.bluegoat.chores.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="completion")
public class Completion {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long completion_id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="person_id", nullable = false)
    private Person person;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="chore_id", nullable = false)
    private Chore chore;
}
```

**CompletionRepository (repository)**

I think I need to add a method to the CompletionRepository for the specific query

```java
package org.bluegoat.chores.repository;

import org.bluegoat.chores.model.Completion;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface CompletionRepository extends JpaRepository<Completion, Long> {

//something like this that gets a list of chores of a given id, done by a person of a given id, and then count the rows in the resultset?
List<Completion> getChoreByPerson(long person_id, long chore_id); 

}
```

---

**CompletionService (service interface)**

```java
public interface CompletionService {

// And add this to the CompletionService interface?
    List<Completion> getChoreByPerson(long person_id, long chore_id);
}
```

---

And finally Override the method in the CompletionServiceImpl
**CompletionServiceImpl (service)**

```java
@Service
public class CompletionServiceImpl implements CompletionService {

    private CompletionRepository completionRepository;

    public CompletionServiceImpl(CompletionRepository completionRepository) {
        super();
        this.completionRepository = completionRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Completion getChoreByPerson(long person_id, long chore_id) {
        Optional<Completion> completion = completionRepository.getChoreByPerson(person_id, chore_id);
// Not sure what I am putting in here
    }
```

From the hours of videos and reading, I think I am on the right track, I just can't seem to get it to click.

**There is something wrong about the person_id and chore_id being long and the Completion model fields being of type Person and Chore.**

Comment: I don't think any query should begin with get or something like this. 
Maybe you should consider having a method named this way in your repository : List<Completion> findByChoreAndPerson(Chore chore, Person person);
Unless you want to have a native query.... In this case you may have something like this 

@Query(value = "SELECT FROM Completion c WHERE c.personId = :personId AND c.choreId = choreId")
List<Completion> getChoreByPerson(@Param("personId") long personId, @Param("choreId") long choreId);

Comment: I tried adding the method to the repository List<Completion> findByChoreAndPerson(Chore chore, Person person); However this produces some errors. "Error creating bean with name 'completionController'" "Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'completionServiceImpl'" "At least 2 parameter(s) provided but only 1 parameter(s) present in query" The error does not present when the method contains only one parameter.

Comment: Thanks David, this worked out for me with a native query for now.     @Query(
            value = "SELECT * FROM cms.completion WHERE person_id=:person_id and chore_id=:chore_id",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<Completion> findChoreByPerson(@Param("person_id") long person_id, @Param("chore_id") long chore_id);

Comment: nice to hear second solution worked fine.  First should have also worked.